# Как посмотреть значение переменной статик метода через юнит тест

Tags: python, юнит-тесты

у меня есть статичный метод и он возвращает переменную допустим spot мне надо посмотреть в моем тесте через print что это за переменная которую возвращает @staticmethod допустим функция называется change_spot. я сначала думал писать
`print(change-spot.spot)`
но в таком коде ошибка

Comment: print(change_spot())

Comment: спасибо, но например ясли я захочу ее сравнить в assert то как мне поступить?

Comment: Так же как и любой другой ассерт, очевидно